# Change text color on listView with buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I'm creating a ListView with buttons and having some issues.
My activity need to do 2 different actions for each action (`ItemClick` and `buttonClick`).

I assumed that:

1 – Because I has button on list items, I cant use `OnItemClickListener()`. Right?

So, I create layout for list items and make it clickable.

**listitem_textview_button.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/selector_list_item">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/listitem_textview_button_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/edit" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listitem_textview_button_txv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_textview"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listitem_single_line_w_button_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that I've created a selector for the layout and a stateColorList for Textview.

**selector_list_item.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_disabled" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_disabled" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_transition" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_transition" />

    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_focus" />
</selector>
```

**selector_textview.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/black" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/black" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/black" />
   <item android:color="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

2 – This is the best way to implement a ListView with custom items (included TextView Colors)?

The above code does not change the color of textViews when I click on items.

In some tests I saw that the text color changes when:
1. Using arrows of emulator.
2. Removing the button of ListView item.

Where is the problem?

prinscreens:
listitem selected by arrow device (text black, **ok**!)

[image: listitem selected by emulator arrow]

listitem clicked by finger (text red, should be black, **fail**)

[image: listitem clicked by finger(using device)]

**answer:**

add `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to TextView.

Comment: If text color changes when using emulator arrows maybe that's mean you have not set the right property? And I noticed you've set the clickable property on the `RelativeLayout` but isn't your textview who need to be `clickable` ? Or can you make a printscreen of your interface for clarifications about what your trying to achieve?

Comment: @SanFrancesco, see the examples added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it, your layout is clickable but you have buttons? Is the button for selecting a row?

If I were you I would not make anything clickable except the button. android:focusable="false" android:clickable="false"

Then you can in the button listener set the selection on a row manually:

```
getListView().setSelection(position);
```

Let me know if this works.

[EDIT] The real problem is that the TextView needs to be clickable, not the layout.

Comment: But I have two diffent actions for list Item: Click on row(layout) -> open ActiviyA. Click on button -> Open ActivityB. Then, I need the selectors works for both(layout and text).

Comment: @Rodrigo So it is the TextView that is clickable then, and NOT the layout.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why Layout do not pass selected state to childView(TextView) ?

Comment: @Rodrigo As soon as you have a row with views inside, then the layout doesn't want to have anything to do with user interaction.